# undefined method Database\Factories\ Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, factory, laravel-8

My doubts about the factories and the seeds.
I try to do the migrations with the seeds and I get the following issue. `Call to undefined method Database\Factories\PostFactory::faker()`

I not have very clear where to make the call, if in a separate file, such as PostSeeds or how I am doing it here.

This is the main file DatabaseSeeder.php

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();

        Storage::makeDirectory('posts');

        User::create([
            'name' => 'Fernando',
            'email' => 'cainuriel@gmail.com',
            'password' => '$2y$10$.CjCfp.mzo.AUMPZj0n7mOK3zU6QmrabKXwaYcHNFtK1qWHRqf4Xe',
        ]);

        Category::create([
            'name' => 'Plagas',
            'slug' => 'plagas',

        ]);

        Category::create([
            'name' => 'Enfermedades plantas',
            'slug' => 'enfermedades-plantas',

        ]);

        Category::create([
            'name' => 'Cultivo ecológico',
            'slug' => 'cultivo-ecologico',

        ]);

        Category::create([
            'name' => 'Consciencia ecológica',
            'slug' => 'consciencia-ecologica',

        ]);

        Post::factory(10)->create();
    
        
    }
}
```

this is the main file My Postfactory.php where I do the fakers data.

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $name =  $this->faker->unique()->sentence();

        return [
            
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => Str::slug($name),
            'extract' => $this->faker->text(250),
            'body' => $this->faker->text(2000),
            'status' => 2,
            'category_id' => Category::all()->random()->id,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'url_image' => 'posts'.$this->faker('public/storage/posts', 650, 490, null, false)

        ];
    }
}
```

I don't know if it will also be useful to show the migration with the table structure

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');

            $table->text('extract');
            $table->longtext('body');

            $table->enum('status', [1, 2])->default(1); // 1. Borrador. 2. Publicar.

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

            $table->string('url_image')->default('default.png');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: run "composer dump-autoload" first and use factory function like this may work. "\App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create();"

Comment: No rules. two ways I did it. ` '\App\Models\Post'::factory(10)->create();` and `      \App\Models\Post::factory(10)->create();` I ejecuted the command `composer dump-autoload` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you have `use HasFactory` trait in the Post model and as you are using laravel 8 so, replace your `url_image` in Postfactory.php with the following:

```
'url_image'  => $this->faker->image('public/storage/posts', 650, 490, null, false)
```

Comment: Yes, is verificated.. `class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;`

Comment: Replace your `url_image` key => value in Postfactory.php with the following:
`'url_image'  => $this->faker->image('public/storage/posts', 650, 490, null, false)`

Comment: "Cannot write to directory "public/storage/posts" 
we will have to create the folder to solve it? and no will be inside public..

Comment: It is clear that this is the problem line. What is not solved by creating the folder. I have simply commented on it and will place a default image

Comment: In `DatabaseSeeder` replace the line `Storage::makeDirectory('posts');` with `
$folder = public_path('/storage/posts');
if (!File::exists($folder)) {
    File::makeDirectory($folder, 0755, true, true);
}`
 and in `UserFactory` replace `url_image` with 
`'url_image' => $this->faker->image(public_path('/storage/posts'), 650, 490, null, false),
`

Comment: I've tried it on my side. It will surely work now :)

Comment: is this library `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;;`? and What is this parameter.. "0755'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231943/discussion-between-abdullah-shakir-and-fernando-lopez).